# Best practice for using files from github projects

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, configuration, tmux

I'm using the tmuxinator ruby gem which I installed via `gem install tmuxinator`,as per the projects github installation instructions.

[tmuxinator link](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/)

As part of their installation instructions they specify also downloading a "completion" file from the repo and linking to it from your shells rc file.

My question: Seeing as I install the project as a ruby gem and not from cloning their github repo if I just download the file needed it wont be updated. Should I instead clone the repo and keep it somewhere, pointing to that location from the zshrc?

Is there a best practice or typical way people do this? Otherwise it seems like I either don't keep my files updated or I have to clone every project repo that works this way?

Comment: From the `tmuxinator.gemspec` it would look like the completion files are part of the gem, so the file in question - `tmuxinator.zsh` should already be on your system. See if you can track it down and just use the absolute path in `~/.zshrc`: `source /abs/path/to/tmuxinator.zsh`. Unless the path changes with each update, it should keep work and always be up to date with the installed gem.

Comment: You're correct Adaephon I should have checked that first. Thanks.

Comment: @Adaephon the path depends on the version of the gem currently installed. A symlink will break on upgrade if the old version is removed, so I wrote the code in the answer below to catch that and update appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something which will work in either `zsh` or `bash` to achieve what you're after.

If you do a `gem clean` to remove an old version of `tmuxinator`, it will fix things up for you when the code is next run (ie at next shell startup if in your `.zshrc`)

```
# Allow shell-specific code
function sh_is_zsh { [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; }
function sh_is_bash { [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]]; }

# Update "tmuxinator.{z,ba}sh" if needed
tmuxinator_source="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/tmuxinator/tmuxinator.$(sh_is_zsh && echo zsh || echo bash)"
# If not a regular file or symlink to one
if [[ ! -f $tmuxinator_source ]]; then
    # If doesn't exist or is a symlink to nowhere
    if [[ ! -e $tmuxinator_source ]] || [[ -L $tmuxinator_source ]] && [[ ! -e $tmuxinator_source ]]; then
        echo "Creating ${tmuxinator_source##*/} symlink:"
        tmp=$(gem which tmuxinator) # tmuxinator executable
        tmp=$(readlink -f "${tmp%/*}/../completion") # completion scripts dir
        ln -fsv "$tmp/${tmuxinator_source##*/}" "$tmuxinator_source"
        unset tmp
    else
      echo "Not creating symlink at at existing:"
      ls -lF "$tmuxinator_source"
    fi
fi

source "$tmuxinator_source"
unset $tmuxinator_source
```

<sup>Note this is `shellcheck` clean for extra brownie points.</sup>